# Reducing a higher order nonlinear ODE to a system of first order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE that I am trying to reduce is:

$$
y''' + 4\,y'' + y' + 6\,y - 2y^{2} = 0
$$

I start by letting
$$
y = y_1
$$
$$
y' = y_2
$$
$$
y'' = y_3
$$
$$
y''' = y_4 = 2y_1^2 - 4y_3 - y_2 - 6y_1
$$

However, due to the term $2y_1^2$, I believe that this set of functions cannot be put into matrix form, and hence, I am stuck here.

I would very much appreciate any guidance. :)

Comment: yes, it is non-linear therefore no matrix form.

Comment: How would I manipulate it so that I can put it into matrix form? Would I do something like y0 = y^2?

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you that, this equation is non-linear thus you cannot use any method designed for linearity properties. For any nontrivial solution $y_0$, $c*y_0$ is no longer a solution, where $c$ is a constant.